# Mapbox navigation package when added shows error in gradle build.

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, mapbox, mapbox-android

I am creating a blank project in which I add mapbox navigation package `compile 'com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-navigation:0.6.3'` in the gradle file. It shows error in appcompat file like this:-

```
Error:Failed to resolve: com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0
```

eventhough I use different version of Appcompat file. Before adding navigation package, everything was fine. Can someone please help me to find out this weird error.

Here is my app's gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.aadhilahmed.test7"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-navigation:0.6.3'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.Starting from version 26 of support libraries make sure that the repositories section includes a maven section

```
 allprojects {
        repositories {
            jcenter()
            maven {
                url "https://maven.google.com"
            }
        }
    }
```

For Gradle build tools plugin version 3.0.0

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, the problem got solved by using the first technique itself. Another correction which I had to do to make it work was to add appcompat v7:26.1.0 at the last.

Comment: @Aadhil Ahmed ok thats good.i also thought you are using `appcompat v7:25.1.0` that is a problem.anyway your problem solved. if my answer is help full please upvote.

Answer (score 3):

Specify:

```
compile ('com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-navigation:0.6.3') {
    transitive = false;
}
```

Comment: This succeeds in gradle build but I cannot access the MapboxNavigation classes in the code.